# LC3 assembly-how to print the next character of a character

Tags: assembly, lc3

My aim is to create a program that receives a letter and then prints the "next letter".To be more specific,if the input is "P",the output should be "Q".
This is my code:

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA R4,DATA
LDR R0,R4,#0
ADD R0,R0,#1
TRAP X21
HALT

DATA .FILL x5001
.END
```

x5001 has definitely "P",I have checked it.So I am exmpecting to see a "Q" as output.However,I get a strange looking symbol together with P instead!What's wrong with this code?Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of `x5001` try using `x0050`.

Comment: Well,that works for that particular case!Thanks!However,I really need to use x5001 ,because this is a part of a bigger program...5001 is the adress of the first element of a file that contains characters unfortunately.After I turn P into Q,I must go to the next adress (5002),take the character and find the next!

Comment: If it's an address, you have to dereference it once more with `LDR`.

Comment: Now I got D instead  of Q for some reason..!

Comment: When you say "x5001 is the address of the first element of a file", does that mean you are loading two files into the LC3 simulator before running your program? or are you using a different simulator / assembler?

Comment: I am loading two files